# Values of declared Map gets retained after going back from next page

Tags: java, jsp, collections

I am creating a project using JSPs and Servlets. I have a Map declared in a servlet which captures different values. But the problem is when I go to the next page and press back, the values of the Map gets retained and again gets added up with new values. Eventually, when the value is passed, I get an erroneous result. I have initialized the Map in the beginning but still, the values are retained. Can you please help me with a solution so that the values of this particular map gets deleted every time I press the back button?

This is how I am putting elements in the map:

```
standardTSEffort=(float)mapSelection.get("TS");
advancedTSEffort=taf3rdpartyEffort+bpca3rdEffort+tsreportEffort;
mapSelection.replace("TS", standardTSEffort+advancedTSEffort);
```

Now I am passing the data to JSP :

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("SelectionMap", mapSelection);
```

However, when I click on the back button to revisit the previous JSP, the values of the list is not re-initialized and all the values get added up (previous+recent). How can I take care of this?

Comment: Is this a `Spring` application?

Comment: Nope @TheHeadRush

Comment: When loading your page, your backend java code can simply check if the provided attribute (your map) is empty. If it is not empty - simply clear the map.